# Assembling Sharepoint2013 shreds

Tags: sharepoint-server

Is it possible to re-assemble shreds to make original file with latest version?

I have a DB backup of Sharepoint 2013 and i am fetching data from it using eclipse-JAVA and want that using Input/Output operations original file to be stored on my PC.

Comment: As long as the backup isn't altered, it should be fine...

Comment: Thank you Benny , what i have to do for this??

Comment: can u please help and share steps ??I m trying but not getting the whole data in readable form.

Answer (score 1):

Without an intimate understanding of the Cobalt binaries that take care of shredding, unlikely that you'll be able to reproduce the file [accurately]. As far as I'm aware, there are no commercial products to do so.